# Formatting issue with function returning answer on one line and on the next having the equation equal a boolean value

Tags: python

Code for add function:

```
def __add__(self, rightSide):
        """
        Purpose: Adds two fractions together to get the sum
        :param rightSide: Placeholder for second fraction to be calculated with original fraction
        :return: None
        """
        numer = self.__numerator * rightSide.getDenominator() + self.__denominator * rightSide.getNumerator()
        denom = self.__denominator * rightSide.getDenominator()
        new_frac = Fraction(numer, denom)
        print(new_frac)
```

Driver code:

```
print(f'{frac_a} + {frac_b} = ', frac_a + frac_b)
```

Output:

```
16/15
2/5 + 2/3 =  None
```

When I have frac_a at the end of the formatting code, it will print 2/5 after the equal sign. But when I add the operator and frac_b, it outputs what js shown.

Comment: I believe the `__add__` function should _return_ the Fraction, not _print_ it.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value after adding

```py
def __add__(self, rightSide):
        """
        Purpose: Adds two fractions together to get the sum
        :param rightSide: Placeholder for second fraction to be calculated with original fraction
        :return: None
        """
        numer = self.__numerator * rightSide.getDenominator() + self.__denominator * rightSide.getNumerator()
        denom = self.__denominator * rightSide.getDenominator()
        new_frac = Fraction(numer, denom)
        print(new_frac)
        return new_frac
```

Otherwise, it will return None by default as your output.